# Unable to execute Perl script unless Perl is inserted before script name

Tags: perl, execution

Running Lubuntu - 
Beginner Perl programmer

Script is `XXX.pl` located at `~/projects/XXX/XXX.pl`

First line is the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Permission to run is set to Anyone.

In directory `~/projects/XXX`, the command

```
~/projects/XXX$ perl XXX.pl
```

works as desired, but the command

```
~/projects/XXX$ XXX.pl
```

Fails with `XXX.pl: command not found`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Try entering 'which perl' at the command line. The resulting path should be the path typed out in the first line. Regarding permissions, chmod u+x XXX.pl should be enough

Comment: try `./XXX.pl` - e.g. your `$PATH` (where shell searching for the executables) doesn't includes the `.` (current dir).

Comment: To Amnon,
which perl gives:
/usr/bin/perl

Comment: To jm666,

./XXX.pl 
gives:
bash: ./XXX: No such file or directory

Comment: A nasty catch is when you got your script from a Windows system. In that case, the line terminator is CR-LF instead of LF for Linux. If you try to run such a script on Linux, the CR character will be considered part of the interpreter name and you will get a command not found error. The solution in this case: run the command `dos2unix XXX.pl` and retry.

Comment: @Peter Saly: Could you show us the output of the command `hexdump XXX.pl | head -n1` please? Just to make sure we don't have the encoding problems Hellmar Becker is talking about.

Answer (score 5):

The two usual options to execute your Perl script are:

```
perl XXX.pl
```

or

```
./XXX.pl
```

Both ways assume that your current working directory contains the script *XXX.pl*, otherwise it won't work.

As already pointed out by jm666 in the comments, you can usually not execute a program or script from your current working directory without prepending `./`, primarily because of security reasons. Now, you may wonder why it's necessary.

**Explanation:**

Your shell uses the contents of an environment variable called `$PATH` to find out about where external commands (non-builtin programs) are located in your filesystem. If you want to see what's in `$PATH`, just type the following in your shell:

```
echo $PATH
```

Now you can see that the `$PATH` variable does NOT contain your current working directory. The consequence is that your shell is not able to find the program *XXX.pl*. By prepending `./` you instruct the shell to execute the program which comes after.
But there are two requirements if you want to execute your Perl script with `./script.pl`:

1. The script has to be executable (check with `ls -l`)
2. The first line (shebang line) has to be `#!/path/to/your/perl` because your shell needs that information to find the perl interpreter in order to run your script

*However*, #1 and #2 are NOT required when you execute your script with

```
perl XXX.pl
```

because it invokes the perl interpreter directly with your script.

See [how to make Perl scripts executable on Linux](https://perlmaven.com/hashbang) and [make the script itself directly executable with chmod](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/invoking.html) for some more details.

Comment: please @inferno, add an explanation yourself to the use of `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, to ensure it will run with a non-system perl, for example, after installing Perlbrew (which is a good practice when beginning Perl)

Comment: Yes, I was about to add this but then I realized that it can cause problems when you run your script as root. In this case the wrong perl interpreter might be chosen.

Comment: @vanHoesel, If you want your script to run with a Perl other than `/usr/bin/perl`, you should include that path, not use `env`. (Changing the path in the shebang line should be done by the script's installer. MM and MB both adjust the shebang line when installing a script.)

Answer (score 1):

### Can the script be found?

Is `.` in your path? If it's not, add it to your path, or use `./XXX.pl` instead of `XXX.pl`.

### Can the script be executed?

Do you have execute permission to the file? Fix using `chmod u+x XXX.pl`.

### Is the interpreter correct?

`which perl` will tell you which interpreter is used when you use `perl XXX.pl`. That's the path that should be on your shebang (`#!`) line.

Comment: 1) I am in the directory with the script is stored. So no need for a path to it.
2) Yes the file is executable. (By default all new scripts are automatically made executable

Comment: Re "*I am in the directory with the script is stored. So no need for a path to it*", [You are mistaken!](https://pastebin.com/LFe5dA8Z) On unix systems, a program in the current directory isn't executed unless you use provide a path to the program (e.g. `./program`) or `.` is in `PATH`.  This means you've only checked 1 of the three possible issues.